# Mongo shell "this app can't run on your pc, to find a version for your pc, check with the software publisher."

Tags: windows, mongodb, shell

today I tried to run mongo shell command and it throws me an error: "this app can't run on your pc, to find a version for your pc, check with the software publisher."
I also use clients for Mongodb like Compass and it works fine. Have you any idea what is wrong with the shell? I am on 64bit Win 10 and the Mongo server version is 4. THX

Answer (score 2):

As I found here https://superuser.com/a/926213/613454 the problem is in mongo.exe file which has 0 bytes. Yesterday it worked properly and today it has 0 bytes. Miracle.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue, when attempting to start the "mongod" service. For me this was being caused due to ambiguity around multiple mongod.exe binaries, even though the PATH environment variable is set in Windows.

To resolve this all I did is, in terminal/cmd-prompt, changed directory (CD) into the folder where mongod.exe resides, e.g.:

```
cd \Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin
```

After which, tried to start the mongod service and voila :)

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongod --config E:\\Mongo\\mongo.config --serviceName "MongoDB" --serviceDisplayName "MongoDB-Fin-Server" --serviceDescription "MongoDB primarily for xxx process."
```

This resolved the issue for me, hope this helps others.